# Unserialize Cart data - Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I am listing orders whose transaction status is successfull,

```
$draft_orders = CashfreeResponse::with('draftOrder')->where('txStatus', 'SUCCESS')->get();
```

I am getting results for the above query as expected,

In the DraftOrder table I am saving my cart as serialized data, I am looking to unserialize the cart data,

### **Model**

**User**

```
public function draft_orders()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(DraftOrders::class, 'id', 'user_id');
    }
```

**DraftOrder**

```
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
}

public function cashfreePaymentResponse()
{
    return $this->hasMany(CashfreeResponse::class, 'draft_order_id', 'id');
}
```

**Payment**

```
public function draftOrder()
        {
            return $this->belongsTo(DraftOrders::class,'draft_order_id');
        }
```

**Table Contents--**

**user**

> name | email | password

**payment**

> order_id | txStatus

**draftorders**

> user_id | cart

Also, I was wonderting how do I get the user table details in the above query

Comment: can u please post the `CashfreeResponse` model over here

Answer (score 0):

you can simply use 
**unserialize**($draft_orders->draftOrder);

And for user
$draft_orders = CashfreeResponse::with('draftOrder','user')->where('txStatus', 'SUCCESS')->get();

in this query you can get user data from $draft_orders->user

Comment: Could you please share me the complete query for unserializing data!!

Comment: $draft_orders = CashfreeResponse::with('draftOrder')->where('txStatus', 'SUCCESS')->get();
foreach($draft_orders->draftOrder as $draft){
    $a = unserialize($draft);
}
in $a you will get data of drafts